# SQL Join with MAX

Tags: sql

I have two tables (serverlogdetail a, serverlogid b) that tack user activity
An user can have different log in several times (a.entrydate) in a day in to different applications (b.appname)
For all the applications to which an user has access I need to return a list with the last time he/she logged in.

```
SELECT  b.appname ,max(to_char(a.entrydate)),  a.username,  a.msgnumber
  FROM serverlogdetail a, serverlogid b

  WHERE a.msgnumber = 1020055 
  AND A.entrydate BETWEEN (SYSDATE-90) AND SYSDATE

GROUP BY b.appname, a.dbname, a.username,a.msgnumber, a.entrydate
ORDER BY b.appname, max(to_char(a.entrydate))
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Do you need the msgnumber in the results?

Comment: there is no `join` of `a` and `b` - it will select all the rows in `b` and multiply with the records you select from `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.appname , a.username,  a.msgnumber, max(to_char(a.entrydate))
FROM serverlogdetail a, serverlogid b

WHERE a.msgnumber = 1020055 
AND A.entrydate BETWEEN (SYSDATE-90) AND SYSDATE
AND A.something = B.something           -- the condition you're missing!!!

GROUP BY b.appname, a.username, a.msgnumber
ORDER BY b.appname, max(to_char(a.entrydate))
```